# Jackcess compilation error

Tags: java, database, io, connection, jackcess

i have been searching around for a few days for the answer to this and i just can't seem to get it to work. I have seen exact examples where it is working for them and I try exactly what they do and it is just not working for me.

Basically what i am trying to do is open a local access DB. I have tried numerous methods and this Jackcess seems by far the best library to use, so i am trying to get it to work with that. I have read their cookbook and gone through all of that, and still no luck so i am coming to you guys in the hope of finding a good solution (i have not posted this question anywhere yet). Here is my code (the relevant part)

The only syntax error i am getting is "DatabaseBuilder.Open" and the error is it cannot find the method, even though i have the libraries included for IO

```
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("my.mdb"));
    try {
        Table table = db.getTable("Teams");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Teams.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The program fails to debug once I have click this buttone the only actual message i can fine is

"Cannot find symbol
 Symbol : Method Open(file)
 Location : variable.DatabaseBuilder of type Object"

Comment: Have you considered using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html)? (Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment no I haven't but I will have a look at it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use Jackcess you must have *at least* the following items in the build path for your Java project (or on your CLASSPATH):

- the Jackcess JAR file itself, and
- the JAR files for its two mandatory compile-time [dependencies](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html) from Apache: commons-lang and commons-logging.

In the Eclipse IDE that will look something like this:

[image: Eclipse.png]